# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while converting linkedList to array list

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

Im trying to convert a linkedList into an ArrayList as shown below.

```
private LinkedList<myData> myLinkedList= new LinkedList<myData>();  
public Collection<myData> getData()  
 {
  return new ArrayList<myData>(myLinkedList);  
 }
```

The linkedList might be updated by multiple threads. While testing in production I get the below error. The error is not consistant. So i get it may be once in a week, month or so.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15   
at java.util.LinkedList.toArray(LinkedList.java:866)   
at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:131)   
at org.xxx.yyy.zzz.getData(Data.java:291)
```

Is there any way it could be related to concurrent modification of the linkedList. Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Yes. You should probably synchronize on your instance. Or use the fail fast version.

Comment: If you have multiple threads modifying the `LinkedList` ... yes. When it goes to copy it allocates an array, then iterates through the List. Obviously you're adding an element to the list after the array is created and the array is now too small.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`toArray` failing is only *one* symptom of you doing something fundamentally dangerous.

From the [documentation of `LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

> If multiple threads access a linked list concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it *must* be synchronized externally.

You'll either need to add synchronization (not just for `toArray`, but basically all uses of the list) or use one of the concurrent collections which is *designed* to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

`LinkedList#toArray()` is implemented as such (Oracle JDK 7)

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    Object[] result = new Object[size];
    int i = 0;
    for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
        result[i++] = x.item;
    return result;
}
```

If you add to the `LinkedList` after the `result` array is constructed but before the `for` loop, then the array access expression inside the `for` loop will cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when trying to access an index larger than the original `size`.

You should really put some synchronization barriers so that doesn't happen.